# Android app fail to connect on startup and after loaded

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

Most of the time I try to open the app, I get one of the messages presented below.

**Message on the left:**
If the "retry" option is touched, it takes about 2~3 seconds showing the loading animation and this screen appears again.

**Message on the right:**
Some times, I am able to open the application, but by the time the contents should be appearing, I get the same type of message.

[image: Fail to load message] [image: Fail to load contents after app opened]

**To test the WiFi connectivity:**
After the screenshot on the left, I have opened other applications and they were able to connect to the internet and update their contents.
Tried again to open the application and all went well, but instead of contents I got the message viewed on the screenshot of the right.

---

**Model Number:** LG-P700
**Android Version:** 4.0.3
**Kernel version:** 3.0.8-perf (Wed Dec 12 20:18:47 KST 2012)

<sup>Any other information about the device, please feel free to ask.</sup>

Comment: I get this sometimes as well, even when I have a good connection.

Comment: Wasn't this [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192264/152859) already?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think the behavior has changed in version .18 (released today).

Comment: @AsheeshR OK, glad I didn't vote to close as dupe then. Hmm... so should we close that other question as "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes. Just confirmed on my phone. VTCed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of changes to the initial loading of the application from a cold start (e.g. when nothing from it is in memory) which seem to have fixed this. If you see it happening again let me know.